# How to avoid DisplayLink dock monitors disconnecting intermittently?

Tags: arch-linux, usb, display, displaylink

### Symptoms

Every few minutes/hours the displays connected to the USB3 DisplayLink dock turn off for a few seconds and back on again.

### Hardware

- Dell docking station model D6000
- USB3 connection to HP laptop (happens on at least three different models)
- DisplayPort connections to two HP monitors

### OS

- Arch Linux
- Ubuntu 20.04

### Software

- displaylink 5.3.1.34-4 and other versions

### Logs

I was lucky to catch only a few log entries in the journal while one of these instances happened. I've included *all* the raw logs around this time, including before the disconnect and after the reconnect:

```
Dec 04 09:54:25 host gnome-shell[1676]: libinput error: event5  -       Das Keyboard: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 14ms, your system is too slow
Dec 04 09:55:43 host kernel: usb 4-1.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Dec 04 09:55:43 host kernel: usb 4-1.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
Dec 04 09:55:43 host kernel: cdc_ncm 4-1.1:1.5 ens4u1u1i5: unregister 'cdc_ncm' usb-0000:37:00.0-1.1, CDC NCM
Dec 04 09:55:43 host NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1607028943.8418] device (ens4u1u1i5): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Dec 04 09:55:43 host dhcpcd[950]: ens4u1u1i5: removing interface
Dec 04 09:55:43 host kernel: usb 4-1.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U1 failed.
Dec 04 09:55:43 host kernel: usb 4-1.1: Set SEL for device-initiated U2 failed.
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: usb 4-1.1: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: usb 4-1.1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=767), cval->res is probably wrong.
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: usb 4-1.1: [4] FU [Mic Capture Volume] ch = 2, val = -4592/7680/16
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: usb 4-1.1: Warning! Unlikely big volume range (=672), cval->res is probably wrong.
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: usb 4-1.1: [7] FU [Dell USB Audio Playback Volume] ch = 6, val = -10752/0/16
Dec 04 09:55:44 host upowerd[1197]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:37:00.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.1
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: cdc_ncm 4-1.1:1.5: MAC-Address: 9c:eb:e8:f2:8e:31
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: cdc_ncm 4-1.1:1.5: setting rx_max = 16384
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: cdc_ncm 4-1.1:1.5: setting tx_max = 16384
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: cdc_ncm 4-1.1:1.5 usb0: register 'cdc_ncm' at usb-0000:37:00.0-1.1, CDC NCM, 9c:eb:e8:f2:8e:31
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: usb 4-1.1: usbfs: process 173165 (ActiveCommandQu) did not claim interface 0 before use
Dec 04 09:55:44 host NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1607028944.2517] manager: (usb0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/9)
Dec 04 09:55:44 host systemd-udevd[181574]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Dec 04 09:55:44 host boltd[941]: probing: started [1000]
Dec 04 09:55:44 host systemd-udevd[181574]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: cdc_ncm 4-1.1:1.5 ens4u1u1i5: renamed from usb0
Dec 04 09:55:44 host upowerd[1197]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:02.0/0000:37:00.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.1
Dec 04 09:55:44 host NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1607028944.2787] device (usb0): interface index 8 renamed iface from 'usb0' to 'ens4u1u1i5'
Dec 04 09:55:44 host NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1607028944.2835] device (ens4u1u1i5): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Dec 04 09:55:44 host NetworkManager[1027]: <info>  [1607028944.2859] settings: (ens4u1u1i5): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Dec 04 09:55:44 host systemd-udevd[181575]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
Dec 04 09:55:44 host systemd-udevd[181575]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Dec 04 09:55:44 host dhcpcd[950]: ens4u1u1i5: waiting for carrier
Dec 04 09:55:44 host dhcpcd[950]: ens4u1u1i5: waiting for carrier
Dec 04 09:55:44 host kernel: cdc_ncm 4-1.1:1.5 ens4u1u1i5: network connection: disconnected
Dec 04 09:55:47 host boltd[941]: probing: timeout, done: [2973976] (2000000)
```

### Other

This has been observed by a bunch of people on similar software and hardware, not just the ones above. It also happens on Windows 10, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but I'll still provide answer since it might help new DisplayLink users. I've used DisplayLink with both Linux and Windows, had two different devices. Here are the common points that were causing issues. I'll address Windows too since some users might be dual-booting.

- Check the **USB suspend/powersave** settings, and try to disable them, especially if you have displaylink device connected via USB hub or a dock. Powertop is a helpful tool for that under Linux. Under Windows, try power saving settings.
- Some **issues** can be **laptop specific**, check for any additional BIOS power saving configuration for graphics, USB or general performance.
- Check if you don't have **wifi adapter or a Bluetooth wireless device too close to the DisplayLink adapter**. I had this issue with my older laptop, using the other USB or connecting via LAN cable solved it.
- Check what **versions of Displaylink and Evdi** you're using. Your distro might have older versions that don't have some of the newer bugs fixed. Also some Linux kernel versions have bugs or features that are not yet integrated with Evdi. Try both latest stable and LTS version of kernels if available.
- Try **switching to default Intel modesetting** driver on Linux and install the latest DisplayLink and graphics drivers on Windows.
- If it still won't work, check the **[evdi github page](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi)**, especially the [Issues](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues) section. You might find a hint or advice what version works best.
- **[Arch wiki DisplayLink page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/DisplayLink)** offers some good installation and troubleshooting tips for Displaylink (suspend issues, display recognition problems, redraw issues, etc.).

Comment: Very thorough answer, +1. I'm not using DL anymore (USB3 FTW) so I'll just mark as accepted.

Comment: Thank you. Same here, I just use it occasionally at work. But my advice is to avoid it, if possible. Especially on Linux :)

Comment: What does USB suspend do? Are there any reasons not to turn e.g. USB autosuspend off i.e. is there a reason it defaults to autosuspend?

Comment: This is older article, but explains the issues with USB auto-suspend quite well https://hamwaves.com/usb.autosuspend/en/ TL;DR it can save power, but some devices can misbehave or even stop working.